# Upgrading a mongo cluster

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am looking at adopting a Mongo cluster and am doing research. We hope to have a cluster that can scale from 10k updates per second to 100k updates per second with very write heavy traffic.

The primary question is, If we wanted to move to a newer version, is this possible without downtime?

Would we upgrade one shard / replica at a time and let it rejoin the group and hope it is backwards compatible and doesn't munge the data?

As a bonus, what is a cluster estimate on 10k updates per second? 100k?

I looked at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+FAQ but couldn't find an upgrade procedure.

Comment: I have done it the way you mention, and it has worked. (one at a time upgrades: shutdown node, replace binary, start node). I would like to hear it from a 10gen employee, though, that it should always work like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check the release notes for each version, but the upgrade directions for 2.0 are here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/2.0+Release+Notes#2.0ReleaseNotes-Upgrading

The last two bullet points specifically address your question:

> - To upgrade a replica set. Upgrade the secondaries first one at a time, then stepDown the primary and upgrade the primary. Using the
>     stepDown command is better than simply shutting it down since the
>     failover will happen quicker. To avoid losing the last few updates on
>     failover you can temporarily halt your application (failover should
>     take less than 10 seconds) or change your application code to confirm
>     that each update reaches multiple servers. Note, after upgrading to
>     2.0 you can use the shutdown command to shutdown the primary without losing any safe updates.
> - To upgrade a sharded cluster. Upgrade config servers one at a time, in any order. Since config servers use two phase commit, shard
>     configuration metadata updates will halt until all are up and running.
>     mongos routers can be upgraded in any order.

Downtime is minimal, taking only the time for the Replica Set to acknowledge that the stepDown has occurred, and election/promotion to happen.